git pre-receive hook doesn't send any messages to client
I try develop a git hook to reject all pushes as example.
The git-hook is as follows:
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
exit 1

I get a rejection on a client, but no messages are displayed in the client log, but I have this "hello" in daemon log:
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 254 bytes | 254.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To git:<my_ip>
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git:/<ip addr>'

server log:
[14264] Connection from <my_ip>
[14264] unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE on socket: Input/output error
[14264] Extended attribute "host": <my_ip>
[14264] Request receive-pack for '/'
[14264] hello

What's wrong?
How I can send a message on the reject from hook on git server to client?
Client on git version: win 2.37, server win 2.37
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack


Your configuration works just fine for me on a Linux system. It both sends the message to the client and accepts the push, which is what we would expect. If your goal is to disable all pushes, you could just drop the --enable=receive-pack.

No no, I want to interact with clients, this script is example. Unfortunately, switching to another OS is not possible. Thank you for your test.

you need to echo "hello" >&2 this redirects the output of the echo command to stderr.
works in gitbash but not sure in windows command prompt

No info via gitbash:
user@server MINGW64 /c/rep/test_rep2 (master)
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 257 bytes | 257.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To git:///
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git:///'

you push did not work @t

No, I have the message "pre-receive hook declined", it's means push had been rejected by pre-receive
